# VBA save value from cell before it changes

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet where i implement a score board.
The behavior i need is when the cell that has the score value rises the cell near it, on column b, changes it's color to green, when the the cell score value goes down the cell near it changes it's color to red.

**The cell range where the score is changing is e5:e67**

**In short:**
When the user inputs a number in column f, the score raises in column e, and in column b (on same row) the color must change to green or red

I made this VBA code, but without luck.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("e5:e67")) Is Nothing Then
 If Target.Column = 5 Then
  thisRow = Target.Row
  Dim OldValue As Variant
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Undo
  OldValue = Target.Value
  Application.Undo
  Application.EnableEvents = True
 If OldValue < Target.Value Then
  Range("b" & thisRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
 ElseIf OldValue > Target.Value Then
  Range("b" & thisRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
 End If
 End If
End If
End Sub
```

Here is a screen capture of my ranking sheet:[image]

Comment: When i input a number on cell f5 the score on e5 raises but cell b5 does not change color to green.

Comment: ah ok. The change event is not triggered on a target that changes value via a formula. You need to work with the `Worksheet_Calculate` event.

Comment: In cell e5 i have a formula that increases its on value by 10 points when user inputs a number in cell f5. If user inputs 1 cell e5 grows 10 points, if user inputs 2 cell e5 grows 20 points.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, it was a valuable add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  by intercepting the `Worksheet_Calculate` event. You need to save the old value in a `static` local array, that I call `oldVal`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
  Static oldVal
  If IsEmpty(oldVal) Then
    oldVal = Application.Transpose(Range("e5:e67").Value2)
    ReDim Preserve oldVal(5 To 67)
    Exit Sub
  End If
  Dim i As Long
  For i = LBound(oldVal) To UBound(oldVal)
    If oldVal(i) > Cells(i, "E").Value2 Then Cells(i, "B").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    If oldVal(i) < Cells(i, "E").Value2 Then Cells(i, "B").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    oldVal(i) = Cells(i, "E").Value2
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help, based on your example i was able to implement the full code i needed and now my vba macro is running well. I will mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Integer
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("e6:e67")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Offset(-1) < Target Then
        i = 4
    Else
        i = 3
    End If
    Range("b" & Target.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = i
End If
End Sub
```